# Class App\Http\Controllers\PostController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

Let me just start by saying "I know this question gets asked a lot." believe me when i say nothing has worked for me.

I have created a controller called `PostController`. This is a controller for my blog. When I navigate to my blog i get the following error `Class App\Http\Controllers\PostController does not exist` even though it does exist. The controller is called `PostController.php`. Here is what the route looks like `Route::get('blog','PostController@index');`. I have read that running some `composer` commands will help but none of them have helped me. `composer dumpautoload` as well as `composer update`. Am i missing some step here? Anyone run into a similar problem? Please let me know if additional information is needed.

**EDIT**
Here are the namespaces at the top.

```
use App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Posts;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\PostFormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Here is the whole Controller.

```
<?php 
use App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Posts;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\PostFormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;



class PostController extends Controller {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
    public function index()
    {
      //fetch 5 posts from database which are active and latest
      $posts = Posts::where('active',1)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);
      //page heading
      $title = 'Latest Posts';
      //return home.blade.php template from resources/views folder
      return view('blog/home')->withPosts($posts)->withTitle($title);
    }


/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
      // if user can post i.e. user is admin or author
      if($request->user()->can_post())
      {
        return view('blog.create');
      }    
      else 
      {
        return redirect('blog');
      }
    }


/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
    public function store(PostFormRequest $request)
    {
      $post = new Posts();
      $post->title = $request->get('title');
      $post->body = $request->get('body');
      $post->slug = str_slug($post->title);
      $post->author_id = $request->user()->id;
      if($request->has('save'))
      {
        $post->active = 0;
        $message = 'Post saved successfully';            
      }            
      else 
      {
        $post->active = 1;
        $message = 'Post published successfully';
      }
      $post->save();
      return redirect('edit/'.$post->slug)->withMessage($message);
    }


/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
    public function show($slug)
    {
      $post = Posts::where('slug',$slug)->first();
      if(!$post)
      {
         return redirect('/')->withErrors('requested page not found');
      }
      $comments = $post->comments;
      return view('posts.show')->withPost($post)->withComments($comments);
    }


/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
    public function edit(Request $request,$slug)
    {
      $post = Posts::where('slug',$slug)->first();
      if($post && ($request->user()->id == $post->author_id || $request->user()->is_admin())){
          return view('posts.edit')->with('post',$post);
      }
      return redirect('blog')->withErrors('you have not sufficient permissions');
    }


/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
      //
      $post_id = $request->input('post_id');
      $post = Posts::find($post_id);
      if($post && ($post->author_id == $request->user()->id || $request->user()->is_admin()))
      {
        $title = $request->input('title');
        $slug = str_slug($title);
        $duplicate = Posts::where('slug',$slug)->first();
        if($duplicate)
        {
          if($duplicate->id != $post_id)
          {
            return redirect('edit/'.$post->slug)->withErrors('Title already exists.')->withInput();
          }
          else 
          {
            $post->slug = $slug;
          }
        }
        $post->title = $title;
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        if($request->has('save'))
        {
          $post->active = 0;
          $message = 'Post saved successfully';
          $landing = 'edit/'.$post->slug;
        }            
        else {
          $post->active = 1;
          $message = 'Post updated successfully';
          $landing = $post->slug;
        }
        $post->save();
             return redirect($landing)->withMessage($message);
      }
      else
      {
        return redirect('blog')->withErrors('you have not sufficient permissions');
      }
    }


/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
    public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {
      //
      $post = Posts::find($id);
      if($post && ($post->author_id == $request->user()->id || $request->user()->is_admin()))
      {
        $post->delete();
        $data['message'] = 'Post deleted Successfully';
      }
      else 
      {
        $data['errors'] = 'Invalid Operation. You have not sufficient permissions';
      }
      return redirect('blog')->with($data);
    }


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: From where you are calling `blog` can you share us?

Comment: Do you have a namespace on your controller class?

Comment: Please see namespaces in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `composer dumpautoload` is not helping then check if you have proper `namespace` declaration in `PostController.php` and double check for typos in class name/route declaration.

If this fails check `composer.json` for autoload configuration, it should have something like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

As a side note you could use something like this:

```
Route::get('blog',PostController::class . '@index');
```

or

```
Route::get('blog',\App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class . '@index');
```

With this any decent IDE should give some kind of a warning if it can't find the file/there's a typo

**Edit**:

Your file should have a line like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

At the beggining of the file, right after `<?php` or `<?php declare(strict_types = 1);` if you're using php7 strict mode

Comment: Hello, I have checked and rechecked my spelling about 50 times. I checked my composer.json file and the contents you mentioned are in there.

Comment: I see you updated your question with namespaces you _use_ but do you have `<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;` in PostController.php?

Comment: @IE5Master Can you update your post with whole PostController.php?

Comment: I have added the whole controller

Comment: Yep, you don't have `namespace` declaration at the top of the file. You have `use` statements but you didn't declare that this class is in `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

Comment: Brilliant. Looked over one easy step.

Answer (score 7):

Open App\Provider\RouteServiceProvider.php
and add
this line

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

below this

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

and your error will vanish.

Answer (score 4):

Open App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php and uncomment or add the row:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use laravel 8.* then Open App->Providers>RouteServiceProvider.php and uncomment this line:

protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

Answer (score 0):

This happened in my upgrade from Laravel 7.x to 8.x. My fix was to change my routing from:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

to:

```
Route::resource('posts', \App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class);
```

or if you import the PostController class:

```
Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

The reason for this change is explained in the upgrade from Laravel 7.x to 8.x guide:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#routing

It explains that it 8.x provides support to allow route declarations to use standard PHP callable syntax. The alternative solution is what others have mentioned, and add **protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';** to **RouteServiceProvider**.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, You would have to add class into the **routes\web.php** file as given below:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually really simple you just got to change

`Route::get('blog','PostController@index');`

to this    `Route::get('blog',[PostController::class, 'index']);`