# Class App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

hi m trying to get view of page but it says: Class App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController does not exist

pic of folder structure   https://ibb.co/gMBvwDJ

Route:

```
  Route::match(['get','post'],'/admin/categories/index','CategoriesController@Category');
```

controller:

```
  public function index()
  {
    return view('admin.categories.index');
  }
```

Comment: Your folder structure only shows your views, not your controllers. The controllers are typically under directory `app\Http\Controllers`.

Comment: yes m just showing the views structure

Comment: The error is saying that your Controller is missing though. The views are not really the problem. We can't know if your controller is actually in the correct path and has the correct filename with the information provided.

Comment: plz loot at this hope u will understand the structure  https://ibb.co/CMzHZLs        now it says:    Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class App\Http\Controllers\PostController does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975921/class-app-http-controllers-postcontroller-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you use a wrong definition of the route match, so try this:

```
Route::match(['get','post'], 'CategoriesController@index');
```

and second, make sure that in your `CategoriesController` you use the right namespace, which should be:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

at the very top of the class.

Comment: now it says: 404 error page not found,    m using this URL:    ../public/admin/categories/index

Comment: @programmer0001 okay, then leave the middle part, but the 3d argument should be `CategoriesController@index` instead of yours, as that's the method name.

Comment: Do you have the correct namespace in your controller class? Is your controller in your App/Http folder?

Comment: yes it is in app/Http/Controllers/CategoryController.php .................... and have these lines at top     <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;

Comment: plz loot at this hope u will understand the structure   https://ibb.co/CMzHZLs              now it says Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: @programmer0001 `CategoryController` is different than `CategoriesController` hope you solved it as I see you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you that error because the controller couldn't find the class you are calling so in order to fix the problem, in the top of your controller add

use App{ModalName};

for example if your model for this is called categories,

use App\categories;

as well as add

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: i hv used this like use App\Category;

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your controller is placed in below directory structure or else you have to fix the namespace problem

[image]

Comment: yes the above error has gone now it says page not found

Comment: good ..I think it entered to the controller now...make sure the view file is in correct location