# Target class [PostController] does not exist. but it dose

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

The error I am getting is: `Target class [PostController] does not exist` but it does.

#### Route `web.php`

```php
Route::get('/post', 'PostController@index');
Route::post('/post', 'PostController@store');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('create');
});
```

#### `PostController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Redirect,Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = json_encode($request);
        Post::create($data);

        return back()->withSuccess('Data successfully store in json format');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try command "composer dump-autoload" and Restart your "php artisan serve"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class App\Http\Controllers\PostController does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975921/class-app-http-controllers-postcontroller-does-not-exist)

Comment: Not working showing the same error thanks

Comment: Not working showing the same error thanks @Andrew

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP adding custom namespace using autoloader from composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504980/php-adding-custom-namespace-using-autoloader-from-composer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this line on the top of the (web.php) maybe your problem will resolve

```
 use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
```

Answer (score 5):

This error comes in Laravel new version because there is no namespace prefix being applied to your route groups that your routes are loaded into. In the old version of Laravel, the `RouteServiceProvider` contained a `$namespace` property which would automatically be prefixed onto the controller route.

To solve this, you either can go to `RouteServiceProvider` and uncomment the line:

```php
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Or you can use closure-based syntax:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\PageController;

Route::get('/page', [PageController::class, 'index']);
```

Another way would be to use the fully qualified class names for your Controllers:

```php
Route::get('/page', 'App\Http\Controllers\PageController@index');
```

Comment: now it showing this Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create(): Argument #1 ($attributes) must be of type array, string given, called in

Comment: that's because you are JSON encoding the data. Try `Post::create($request->only('title', 'body', ...))`

Comment: Thanks now this is error :--- Add [title] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Post].

Comment: You could accept the answer since it solves your original question

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu Please, mark this answer as solved/accepted

Comment: @matiaslauriti I'm not the author of this question. :) It's up to Abdullah Al Shahed

Comment: Sorry, I tagged the wrong person ! @AbdullahAlShahed